# How to simplify vba copy paste separate cells values

Tags: vba

I know there is a way to make this code short and quick but it seems that I am too much of a noob to achieve it. I have some merged cells (it's a form that it's supposed to be "standard" but the users keep messing with it and the macro I use will give tons of errors and will not gather the information). What I have managed to do so far was to make another piece of code that opens the "standard" form again and it fills in all data from the user's form.

It works like a charm but now I am tired of looking and asking around since I can not figure out how to simplify it (I know that it must be silly to you but I can not accept the fact that it can not be done - also I can not accept that the "all powerful" VBA must take ages to write so much code for so little thing).

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Workbooks.Open Filename:="...\Standard Formular.xls"
Sheets("Formulaire - Form").Select
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E9").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E11").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E13").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E13").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E15").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E15").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E17").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E17").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E19").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E19").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("E21").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Date
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E28").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E28").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E30").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E30").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E32").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E32").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E34").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E36").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E36").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E38").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E38").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E48").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E48").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E50").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E50").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E52").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E52").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E54").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E54").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E63").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E63").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("G63").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("G63").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("C65").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("C65").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("D65").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("D65").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E65").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E65").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("F65").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("F65").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("G65").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("G65").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E67").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E67").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("A72").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("A72").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("G72").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("G72").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E97").Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
Range("E97").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
ActiveWindow.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Thank you in advance for making the time to help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the sheets you are copying to and from in variables:

```
wsU = Sheets("Sheet name on user form goes here")
Workbooks.Open Filename:="...\Standard Formular.xls"
wsF = Sheets("Formulaire - Form")
```

now instead of flip-flopping between which sheet is activated and instead of using copy and paste as this involves the clip board and can mess up when you start trying to copy and paste in another application while this macro is running try this:

```
wsF.Range("E9").value = wsU.Range("E9").value
```

etc

btw a nice shorthand for this is

```
wsF.[E9] = wsU.[E9]
```

Comment: No problem and welcome to SO. If this solves the issue please mark it as correct (the tick at the top left of the answer) and also you can upvote the answer if you think it's good by clicking the upward pointing triangle also n the top left.

Comment: this solution is amazingly simple and easy to follow - I've just put it into my macro and it just flows !

Answer (score 0):

Do a

```
`sheet("Where i want to paste").range("xxx").value=sheet("Data im copiing").range("yyy").value`
```

for example, your first copy would be:

Sheets("Dont know the name").range("E9").value=Sheets("Formulaire - Form").Range("E9").value